# How to render a template with a html file

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

It is showing me Not found, the requested url was not found on the server.

This is what my lower code looks like:

```
@app.route('/<name>')
def user(name=None):
    return.render_template('test.html', name=name)
```

The test.html file has a boiler plate and this:

```
<h1>Hi, {{name}}</h1>
<p>You are welcome to our school</p>.
```

It gave me a URL but when I click on the URL it shows "Not found. The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

Comment: What url are you trying to access?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your example, you should use render_template() not return.render_template

replace the period with a space

```
@app.route('/<name>')
def user(name=None):
    return render_template('test.html', name=name)
```

Comment: This is correct solution check the documentation here as well 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-templates-in-a-flask-application